# Wxpython: Bind works only on double click, but single click is desired

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a table with checkboxes. I want to bind the box checking to a method `onClick` but that method activates only when I double click a record, while I want it to be activated when a single click is pressed.

```
import wx
from wx import ListEvent


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def onClick(self, event: ListEvent):

        print(event.EventObject)

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'List ctrl example', size=(500, 700))

        self._list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        self._list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Checkbox', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width = 50)
        self._list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Data', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width = 200)
        self._list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Test', format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, width = 200)
        # self._list_ctrl.SetColumnWidth(0, 200)
        self._list_ctrl.EnableCheckBoxes()

        for i in range(0, 50):
            # index = self._list_ctrl.InsertItem(i, '')
            self._list_ctrl.InsertItem(0, '')
            self._list_ctrl.SetItem(0, 1, 'item: ' + str(i))
            self._list_ctrl.SetItem(0, 2, 'label')
            self._list_ctrl.CheckItem(0, True)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.onClick, self._list_ctrl)
        self.Layout()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED` use `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`

Comment: That is only good if you wish to know when the list item was clicked on. More often with Check Boxes, you want to know when it was checked or unchecked. Those event bindings would be `EVT_LIST_ITEM_CHECKED` and `EVT_LIST_ITEM_UNCHECKED`